# Why does the video HTML5 not work?

Tags: html, html5-video, vimeo

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<video src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=12680155" controls="controls">
your browser does not support the video tag
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm using Firefox 3.6.13

Comment: What format is the video? (Must be served with the correct MIME type) See: http://diveintohtml5.org/video.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video tag does not work in IE, if that's the browser you're using.  Also, your HTML does not seem to have a <head> element and corresponding closing tag, I'm not sure if that might impact things poorly in HTML5.

Comment: There's the problem!  Firefox only supports OGG video formats, according to W3C schools at http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_video.asp. Your MP4 videos will work in Chrome and Safari though.

Comment: MP4 will not work in Chrome soon. It will be best to also use WebM, which is supported by Chrome, Firefox and Opera.

Answer (score 0):

In my HTML5 Video Tag, I use video in .mp4, .ogv, .mpg video formats. Then it runs in all the latest HTML5 supported browsers.